Condition for $p$ to divide the discriminant $\Delta_K$ of a number field $K$
I am struggling to solve the following exercise. Could someone explain me how to approach these questions ?
Let $K$ be a number field. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-base of $K$ such that $\mathcal{O}_K=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n  \mathbb{Z}x_i$.
We define $$I:=\{x \in K, \text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x\mathcal{O}_K) \subset \mathbb{Z}\}$$
Then $I$ is a fractional ideal that can be written $I=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}x_i^*$ where $x_1^*, \dots, x_n^*$ is a basis of $K$ such that for all $1\le i,j \le n$, $$\text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x_ix_j^*)=\delta_{i,j}$$
I have already shown this part.
Then we define $\mathcal{D}=I^{-1}$ and we need to show that it is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Show that $$[\mathcal{O}_K : \mathcal{D}]=|\Delta_K|$$

Here it tried to consider the change-of-basis matrix between $(x_i)$ and $(x_i^*)$.
I've shown that its discriminant is equal to $\Delta_K$ but I don't know how to conclude...

Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p\mathcal{O}_K=\mathfrak{p}^e \mathfrak{a}$ with $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ two coprime ideals, $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal, and $e\ge 2$. Show that $\frac 1 p \mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{a} \subset I$

Show that $\mathfrak{p}^{e-1}$ divides $\mathcal{D}$

Conclude that $p$ divides $\Delta_K$


Thank you in advance for your help! I appreciate any guidance or hints.

For 1., consider the fact that the change of basis matrix gives you an isomorphism of  free, finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-modules $I \to \mathcal O_K$. It is then a standard fact that the index of the image of such map equals the determinant.
For 2., the ideal $\mathfrak p\mathfrak a$ is divisible by every prime of $\mathcal O_K$ lying over $p$. Let $L$ be the normal closure of $K$, and consider the set  $P=\{\mathfrak p_1,\ldots,\mathfrak p_r\}$ of primes of $\mathcal O_L$ that lie over $p$. Clearly, every $\alpha\in \mathfrak p\mathfrak a$, seen as an element of $\mathcal O_L$, belongs to each of the $\mathfrak p_i$'s. Now every element $\sigma$ in the Galois group of (the normal closure of) $K$ permutes $P$, because it restricts to an automorphism of $\mathcal O_L$ and hence induces an isomorphism $\mathcal O_L/\mathfrak p_i\to \mathcal O_L/\sigma(\mathfrak p_i)$. It follows that $T^K_{\mathbb Q}(\alpha)$, that is a sum of conjugates of $\alpha$, belongs to each of the $\mathfrak p_i$'s but also to $\mathbb Z$; hence $p\mid T^K_{\mathbb Q}(\alpha)$, proving that $T^K_{\mathbb Q}(\frac{1}{p}\mathfrak p\mathfrak a)\in \mathbb Z$. Your condition follows immediately.

$\frac{1}{p}\mathfrak p\mathfrak a\subseteq I$ implies $D=I^{-1}\subseteq (\frac{1}{p}\mathfrak p\mathfrak a)^{-1}=\mathfrak p^{e-1}$.

By 1. if a prime divides $[\mathcal O_K:D]$ then it divides $\Delta_K$, but on the other hand if a prime $\mathfrak p$ of $\mathcal O_K$ divides $D$ then the norm  of $D$ (that is precisely $[\mathcal O_K:D]$) is divisible by that of $\mathfrak p$. Since $e\ge 2$, by 3. you have that $\mathfrak p$ divides $D$.



Is your main goal to see why $p\mathcal O_K = \mathfrak p^e\mathfrak a$ with $e \geq 2$ implies $p \mid \Delta_K$? Developing the theory of the different ideal $\mathcal D$ just to see "$e \geq 2 \Rightarrow p \mid \Delta_K$" seems like overkill.  This result can be proved by working more directly with $\Delta_K$, not requiring the ideal $\mathcal D$ at all: see here.
That an index of one finite free $\mathbf Z$-module inside another is the absolute value of any matrix of coefficients describing a basis of the smaller module as a linear combination of a basis of the larger module is Theorem 5.1 here.
